# android google map v2 get markers from remote server

Tags: android, sql, maps

Im looking to to build an app that will get markers from remote sql server in android google map v2.There is nothing on it  out there. any pointers or directions will help. I know how to create hardcoded markers  and interct with them.
Thanks, Ofer.

Comment: You may need to clarify if you need help with the google map api, or retrieving data from a sql server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve a set of markers from a sql database and show it on your canvas, you may write a Web Method which queries the database for the markers (based on your search criteria). Invoke the WebMethod using an "HttpWebRequest".